# Mixed content http and https wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, woocommerce, https

I am working on a wordpress website, when i load my website from google chrome i found the following errors: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://example.com/wp-content/themes/woodstock/fonts/woodstock/woodstock.woff?421wez'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` and `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

*Note: i have another domain name but this is an example*
I have tried to install many secured SSL plugin but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Your page is requesting for some resources with HTTP URL instead of https

Comment: You need to make sure your website is set to be HTTPS - look in your wp_options table to make sure that your domain is set to be HTTPS. You can also use a tool like WP Migrate DB to update all HTTP to HTTPS in the database. That might be a better way to go.

Comment: take a look at my request initiator chain: https://www.mydomainname.net/  (use https) then http://mydomainname.net/wp-content/themes/... (use http)

Answer (score 0):

If you change `siteurl` or `home` setting (eg: from ip to domain), WP will render css resource file with **hard code** of url. Some of them maybe `CORS error` issues **just only font link** if you use ip on browser.

[image]

For easy solution:

Manual quick fix `http` -> `https` url it into css file:

```
wp-content/fonts/.... .css
```

[image]

Note: If you have issue on not only font link, eg: image, page link.... Please add this line in `wp-config.php`.
It will convert all of `http` link into `https`

```
/* Overide ssl */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Load your font ressources over https instead:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/themes/woodstock/fonts/woodstock/woodstock.woff?421wez
https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.ttf
```